# How can I create a constant array with some calculation

Tags: c++

I have code

```
int a[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    a[i] = i * i;
}
```

Is there a way to make this array constant so that other code can use it but not change it.

Comment: `constexpr std::array` - go from there. Don't use C-style arrays. Also; The language has `const_cast` so you can never be 100% certain that noone will do nasty things to your `const` thing (unfortunately).

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Detail: C does not have _constant_ arrays.  C does has `const` arrays.  Accepting to change an element of a `const` array is _undefined behavior_.  It might work, might, not, might kill the code.

Comment: Is this literally the code you have?  What's wrong with `const int a[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8 };` ?

Comment: Lu J., I think @paddy meant `const int a[5] = { 0, 1, 4, 9, 16 };`.

Comment: haha @chux yeah I did =/

Comment: @Broman I am using C++.

Comment: @paddy This is not my real code. Just an example. Calculation could be complicated. I don't want to manually do it if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @LuJ. Then don't use the C tag. I removed it for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use `constexpr` function and the `std::array`:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 5> make_array() {
    std::array<int, 5> a{};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        a[i] = i * i;
    }
    return a;
}
//...
const std::array<int, 5> a = make_array();
```

NB. As noted by @M.M, this code is only valid for C++17, as pre-C++17 the `operator[]` on array wasn't `constexpr`.

Comment: Constexpr isn't really needed here.  The jist of solution is the lifting of the initialization into a function.

Comment: note: this code is undefined behaviour NDR prior to C++17, when `operator[]` was made constexpr

Comment: @NathanOliver it does make a difference. For example, if `a` is a global variable, on gcc absence of constexpr generates run-time initialization, and with constexpr the aray is statically initialized.

Comment: @M.M no diagnostic on godbolt for either of compilers: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/I1MLLS

Comment: @M.M ah! Different dialect. I always use C++17 nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Using modern C++ (`array` and an Immediately Invoked Lambda (IIL)), this can be achieved:

```
const auto a = []() 
{
    std::array< int, 5 > x;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i * i;
    }

    return x;
}(); // IIL
```

Using a lambda has benefits over a function call, that you can capture the local variables into the lambda and use them without the values passing through parameters (`[&]` or `[=]` instead of `[]`).

Just like a function the lambda can easily be inlined into your code, so there can be no overhead.